# FORTRAN 95, Problema con format

Tags: fortran

En mi programa de fortran tengo una matriz de números reales la cual defino por pantalla su dimensión.
El caso es que quiero escribir cada elemento con 5 cifras decimales y no se como definir eso en el FORMAT.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si fuera c = 2.5678945 y quisieras imprimirlo por pantalla debes poner

PRINT 9000, c

9000 **FORMAT** (F7.5)

Este F7.5 te escribiría 2.56789 porque escribe 7 cifras contando el . y deja 5 de esas 7 cifras para los decimales